# Use R dplyr/purrr To Get Chi-square Output Matrices By Group

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to get chi-square output matrices (e.g., standardized residuals, expected values) by group using elements of the tidyverse.  Using the mtcars data set, here's where I've started:

```
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(vs, am) %>%
  table() %>%
  chisq.test(.)
```

Which produces the chi-square test statistic.  In order to get standardized residuals, for example, my only successful code is this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(vs, am) %>%
  table() %>%
  chisq.test(.) -> chi.out

chi.out$stdres

     vs am       Freq
1  0  0  0.9523038
2  1  0 -0.9523038
3  0  1 -0.9523038
4  1  1  0.9523038
```

Ideally, I'd like to get the observed values and the standardized residuals into a dataframe format.  Something like this:

```
cbind(as.data.frame(chi.out$observed),as.data.frame(chi.out$stdres))

  vs am Freq vs am       Freq
1  0  0   12  0  0  0.9523038
2  1  0    7  1  0 -0.9523038
3  0  1    6  0  1 -0.9523038
4  1  1    7  1  1  0.9523038
```

Finally, I'd like to do this by group, for example over the cyl column in the mtcars data set.  Seems dplyr and some some version of purrr's map with map_dfr or map_dfc would do the trick but I can't quite pull it together.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I'd like to get chi-square output matrices by group"* Which group? You're not grouping by any variable. Can you add your expected output for the case where you are grouping by `cyl`?

Comment: Should have provided an example of what the output should look like.  See Humpelstielzchen's response/solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my proposal for a solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

mtcars %>% 
  select(vs, am, cyl) %>%
  table() %>%
  apply(3, chisq.test) %>%
  lapply(`[`, c(6,9)) %>%
  melt() %>%
  spread(key = L2, value = value) %>%
  rename(cyl = L1) %>%
  select(cyl, vs, am, observed, stdres) %>%
  arrange(cyl)


   cyl vs am observed     stdres
1    4  0  0        0 -0.6422616
2    4  0  1        1  0.6422616
3    4  1  0        3  0.6422616
4    4  1  1        7 -0.6422616
5    6  0  0        0 -2.6457513
6    6  0  1        3  2.6457513
7    6  1  0        4  2.6457513
8    6  1  1        0 -2.6457513
9    8  0  0       12        NaN
10   8  0  1        2        NaN
11   8  1  0        0        NaN
12   8  1  1        0        NaN
```

This does a chi-square test for each group of `cyl`. The grouping is done implicitly in the `select()` statement. In the end you get the observed values and standardized residuals for every combination of `cyl`, `vs`, `am`. Should be applicable to any dataframe.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That works perfectly!  Thanks so much.  Have to load tidyr (or tidyverse) so that the spread function works.  The NaN's for 8-cylinder vehicles are the result of a matrix with zeros in the marginals.

Comment: Glad to help! Yes it wasn't able to calculate residuals this way and also gave a warning. But it was just a dummy example.